# Where should i store constants of classes in C++?

Tags: c++

Sorry, if this question is banal, I'm quite new to programming.

I want to write a simple program, where I'd use multiple classes. One, for instance would be `Loc`. I already created the header for the class, wrote the constructor, some methods, etc. I'd like to create a lot of these `Loc` elements, but I don't want to do it in the main cpp. Where should I store them, and how should I refer to them later?

For instance, I want to create a 2D array of `Loc` elements, and then fill it up with different elements, how should I go about storing that variable and loading it in the main cpp as a variable again?

Comment: what is  Loc.please explain?Your class name?

Comment: By create you mean: ```Loc *p = new Loc[10];``` or ```Loc a[10];``` ?

Answer (score -2):

From what I understood, is this what you want to do?

```
class Loc
{

 //data members and member functions


};

Loc arr[10];//create 10 Loc elements


main()
{

}
```

Comment: Right, but I'd like to store the array in a different header. Say, I'd add 20 of these Locactions, and I wouldn't like to write that in the main, because that'd bloat it up. Should I just refer to that array as an extern? Sorry, if I'm not making sense, I really blow at explaining myself.

Comment: @SparksH An array cannot be stored in a header. Headers usually contain declarations (and sometimes definitions) but an array is stored somewhere in memory. May sound like hairsplitting, but I suppose that such kind of confusion is actually causing your problem.

Comment: @Downvoters It would be helpful if you let me know where did I go wrong